# How to pass an object from one component to another via navigation route?

Tags: angular

I cannot find how to pass an complex object from one component to another in Angular.

I have two components in different modules in my app, i would like to navigate from one component to another an pass a complex object to the second component.

Component One:

```
buttonSubmit() {
    this._router.navigate(['/app/sales/history',  { product: this.product}]);
}
```

So in the component two i would like to take the `product` object:

```
 this._route.params.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

I tried using `ActivatedRoute` but it doesnt work, on the Angular docs they have examples of parent/child communication, but its not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make service and save data into service.
On Component One:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ProductService.product = this.product;
}
```

On component Two

```
ngOnOnit() {
  this.product = this.ProductService.product;
}
```

In component One parent module some.module.ts add ProductService to providers:

```
@NgModule({
providers: [ProductService]
})
```

in component Two parent module other.module.ts add ProductService to imports:

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [ProductService]
    })
```

Comment: really need to make a service just to pass a little object around?

Comment: try to stringify this.product  and send in this._router.navigate(['/app/sales/history',  { product: this.product}]); but it's a bad practice